# Screen Capture on Windows 10 IoT Core to Remote Server

Tags: windows-iot, screenshot

I have a device that is powered by a Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT Core connected to a 7" touchscreen display and I am trying to figure out how I can take a screenshot every 15 seconds and send it to a server to be processed, I need to do some OCR to monitor the device's status.

I don't have access to the source code for the foreground app that is running, so I looked into my options and the solution I could find would be to make a Background Application that would run the built-in SceenCapture.exe application to save the screen shot file and then transfer it.

I want to try sparing the Micro SD card from the constant writes, what would be the best option to do that?
Ideally I was hoping that there would have been someway to capture the screenshot to memory and send it to the server via HTTP POST, but it doesn't look like that's an option and as far as I can tell there's no way to make a ramdisk since it's IoT Core, so would my only other option (short of connecting a hard drive via USB) be to use the ScreenCapture.exe application and save it to a network share?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you have any joy with this?

Comment: No, I ended up using ScreenCapture.exe to save it to a local folder and then sending that file to the server via HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a much better way to do this. 
As long as I have the administrator credentials I can simply access http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/iot/screenshot (using the correct IP address) to to get a current screenshot, no need to make any changes or install a Background Application.